# Installing Address Book Policy Agent On Exchange 2013

Tags: exchange, exchange-2013

I'm setting up a multi-tenant Exchange 2013 setup. We are trying to install the ABP Agent to segragate address books. I am following [these instructions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj907308%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx). When running this script in the Exchange console we get an error that the dll is not found.

```
Install-TransportAgent -Name "ABP Routing Agent" -TransportAgentFactory "Microsoft.Exchange.Transport.Agent.AddressBookPolicyRoutingAgent.AddressBookPolicyRoutingAgentFactory" -AssemblyPath $env:ExchangeInstallPath\TransportRoles\agents\AddressBookPolicyRoutingAgent\Microsoft.Exchange.Transport.Agent.AddressBookPolicyRoutingAgent.dll
```

Upon further exploration that DLL is in fact missing from the \$exchangepath\TransportRoles\agents folder.

So I am wondering if this was an issue on the original Exchange 2013 install or if this agent is available for download somewhere. After several hours of Googling I've found nothing. Looking for someone that's run into this issue before.

Comment: Same here. I am also trying to locate answer for this situation. Hopefully I'll get the answer soon and then I'll update this thread

Comment: @HassanLatif I am still hunting as well. Please update here if you find something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fixed with Exchange 2013 CU1.

Comment: Thanks - this did the trick thanks for reminding me this question was out there. Here are details -> http://blogs.technet.com/b/exchange/archive/2013/04/02/released-exchange-server-2013-rtm-cumulative-update-1.aspx